# If you get a little bit of impurity on your body after doing wudu, do you have to redo wudu?

Tags: wudu

I read that if you have a little bit of impurity on your clothes (less than a diram) then it is acceptable to pray.

My question is, if you get a little bit of impurity on your body after doing wudu, do you have to redo wudu, or is it ok to pray with the wudu you already have?

Comment: What kind of impurity would you get on your body after doing wudu? I'm a bit confused and ask myself whether you know what is meant by an impurity which makes you lose your "ritual" purity from wudu.

Comment: if there is a puddle of water on the floor with a tiny drop of urine in it.  what if a tiny bit of that gets on you?

Comment: well you can still wash it away